# How do I retrieve the SharePoint Modern site's (Team sites and Communication sites) classification property via Graph API?

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, office365, sharepoint-online, azure-ad-graph-api

How do I retrieve the SharePoint Modern site's (Team sites and Communication sites) classification property via Graph API ?

```
    I've tried /groups endpoint but it only returns the team sites properties, Communications sites are not listed in groups so how do I get those properties in Graph API?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For communication sites, they do not have Microsoft 365 group connected. So /groups endpoint is only available for team sites.

Using Graph API, I don't think it's possible to get the classification property for Communication sites. You could use SharePoint Rest API to get the property. Use the below endpoint: `/_api/site/Classification`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-site-classification

Comment: If my answer helps you, you could accept it :)

Comment: Can I use Sharepoint rest API for production purposes? Is it better than Graph API?

Comment: Yes, you can. And SharePoint Rest API is only used for SharePoint.You could refer to this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/get-to-know-the-sharepoint-rest-service?tabs=csom.